# Problem with the "Use Object Material" setting for Dynamic Paint

Tags: dynamic-paint

I'm attempting to use Dynamic Paint with the Image Sequence setting.  I've followed all the [necessary steps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6221/how-do-i-use-dynamic-paint-with-the-image-sequence-setting) and I also chose to enable the setting *Use Object Material*.

[image: Selecting Use Object Material]

The material should be green, but the .png files that are produced just have the default light blue.

[image: problem with color]

This problem is only with this particular Blender file.  I can't reproduce it a new file.  The scene I created was very complex with many objects, but I've deleted all the objects in the scene and started with a new canvas, but the problem persists.

Surprisingly, if I open a new Blender file and append the brush object and the canvas object and hit *Bake Image Sequence*, it works fine.

[image]

Here's the [Blender file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26300), if you open and hit *Bake Image Sequence*, you'll see the problem.  Any ideas?  Could this be a bug?

EDIT: A [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T38267) was submitted on this and it has been marked as resolved.

Comment: I'm thinking the file is corrupt as it ignores the material setting when painting, creating a new material doesn't work but changing the brush colour does change the colour drawn, whether use material is on or not. Even deleting the brush and canvas and creating it again doesn't help.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize Blender files could become corrupted.  Yes, I will change the brush color, although in my original scene, the brush object also had some texture which I wanted to appear on the canvas.

Comment: I would submit the blend file with a bug report. The problem is unique to that file (or at least the steps to re-produce it are unknown) but it is reproducible with the file and might be fixable, they may work out how it got there or just how to make blender work with that situation.