# Dynamic Paint not showing in rendered image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, dynamic-paint

To make it simple: I have a project using dynamic paint. In the viewport the dynamic paint works as it's supposed to work. But when rendering it the dynamic paint doesn't show/gets rendered.

[image: In Viewport]
[image: In Render View]

I really have no idea what I did wrong so I'm hoping that someone of you knows how to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may do it using the ***Attribute*** node with a *paintmap* information as a factor for mixing two materials. Here's the finished render:
[image]

First press ***Free Bake*** button in the *Dynamic Paint Cache* panel. Delete the *blendcache* folder from your computer.

Now select your sphere/ball and change the *dynamic paint color* to pure white. We'll be using the paint's color as a mask- I guess it's a good idea as you'll have more control over the materials later. 
[image]

In your case you have two different materials creating the radial pattern for *cylinder*. I created only one material for it, unwrapped with *Project from View* and attached a radial texture to it. You should do it too, cause it'd be simplier in the next stages.
[image]

Now ***Bake*** the *dynamic paint*. In the *Dynamic Paint Output* panel press the **'+'** buton in the *Paintmap Layer* window. It should change from red to grey.
[image]

Now in the *Mesh Data* header you have the baked paint information present in *Vertex Colors* panel. Copy the *'dp_paintmap name'* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
[image]

Now set up the nodes as pictured below. Add the ***Attribute node*** and paste the previously copied name in its window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). Now we have the *mask*. Use it as a factor for mixing between the radial texture and anything you like (in my case it's a simple red color *Diffuse* shader, but it may be other material/texture you like).
[image]

Comment: Following problem: When I click on *Bake* it only bakes 204 of the 240 frames. It doesn't stop after the 204th frame. It seems like it is just skips some frames. In the *Dynamic Paint Cache* it says: `204 frames on disk, not exact since frame 5` Frame 6 seems to be the first "gap".

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Everything seemed a bit bugged so I started again from scratch. This time it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear I helped :). BTW You may also use the other dynamic paint method which uses **image sequences**. The answer here shows how to do it in *Blender Internal*, but you may addapt it into *Cycles* easily: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6221/how-do-i-use-dynamic-paint-with-the-image-sequence-setting