# Projecting a grid of points unto a model and displaying collision output

Tags: python, modeling, scripting

I was wondering if there is a way to use blender to project a grid unto a model and only keep the points that the projection collides with, basically I want to simulate a Time of flight sensor that emits a laser grid and receives the reflection of that laser which indicates the presense of an object and its distance, ideally slanted objects would reveive the laser but reflect it to a different direction and thus would not show up on the output of the sensor.
Would this be doable using a python script?
Anything that could set me on the right track would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a scripted solution, but you can achieve a similar effect using a **particle system**.

[image: collision particles]

Create an emitter plane and a particle system. This will have all the particles emitted at frame `start` = `end` = `1.000` and a `lifetime` long enough for the collision.

Set the emission to `grid` and assign a velocity in the correct direction in the `Emitter object` box. Leave all the other options to their defaults (`Newtonian` physics with all the forces = 0) and in `Field weights` remove the effect of Gravity by setting `gravity` to 0.

Last, you would like to render the particles as lines. Select `Line` under `Render`, set `Tail` to zero and `Head` to some value between 0 and 1. Use a high `trail count` and set `Length` as long as your particles lifetime. Also, tick `Length in frames`.

Now, make sure that all the objects that you want to detect have a `Collision` property (with default values).

(Now you can also add another plane - as a "sensor" - behind the emitter and make it collide with the particles that are coming back, killing them. Then you can render the dead particles as dots on the sensor)

Comment: thank you very much, this was auite helpful and clear, I managed to  put together an emitter than is quite similar to what I had in mind, I was not successful in having the second portion of you recommendation work, I am not quite sure how to render the particles that collide with the second plan (sensor receiver).

One more problem I ran into was when I try to apply this during an animation the particle reflection behave oddly, like they keep orinating from a point where the target no longer exists isnce it has moved.

http://recordit.co/CGb8sbpEdG

Comment: Actually, I thought there was an easier way to render "dead" particles. I was wrong: sorry! I can think of two ways to do that: **one** is using Dynamic paint: set the emitter to Dynamic Paint > Brush with your Particle System as a source, then set the "receiver" as a Dynamic Paint > Canvas. You'll have to play around with the settings for a good effect. **Or** you can make the sensor a collision object, with full stickiness, damping and friction, make the particles render as "object" and giving this object a material that is always transparent unless you are extremely close to the sensor.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3489/ This blend file shows an example of the Dynamic Paint method: open it and hit Alt+A to see the detector in action (then you'll have to link the Dynamic Paint information to your material in order to render it, which I haven't done)

Comment: Thanks again Nicola, I followed your instructions and set the emitter to a brush and the receiver to a canvas but I am a bit confused on how to display my canvas output, it must be soemthing ridiculously straightforward so do excuse my ignorance.

Comment: For that you'll need to create a material that uses the dynamic paint information. Here you can find more: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66449/dynamic-paint-not-showing-in-rendered-image (dynamic paint is not a beginner topic, but even if it was there would be nothing to apologize for!!!)

Comment: I appreicate all your help Nicola, you have definitely given me enough to ponder on and play around with, my aim is to simulate the output of Laser grid sensor into a video or a sequence of images and I'll even have to take depth into consideration, hope all of that can be done because I will commit to your method and put sometime into it.