# how to use dynamic paint weight for texturing object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, weight-painting, dynamic-paint

I have a dynamic paint with surface type set to weight, which I use to displace my object. What I want to do is to apply the texture (in cycles) to my object based on the dynamic paint weight. Just using attribute node with dp_weight going into colorRamp doesn't work.

Any answers highly appreciated.

-laurin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to accomplish this as well.

In the point density texture there's an option to source the values from vertex weights. Unfortunately this only seems to work with volumes, as any output that comes from it when used as a surface texture doesn't seem to correspond with the mesh weights.

There's a workaround though, but you have to set your dynamic paint to texture and bake it out, that way you can load it in to Cycles as an image sequence. If you edit the weights you have to re-bake it, so not the most elegant of solutions.

Maybe someone else has a technique that's more efficient?

edit: [workaround tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6221/how-do-i-use-dynamic-paint-with-the-image-sequence-setting?rq=1)

Comment: but how cane i avoid losing my weight stuff that i use for the displacement, which is the main part of my project? and the point density thig doesnt seem to work for me. could you share your node setup maybe?

Answer (score 2):

i did it! just add a second canvas with vertex format and paint surface type, disable dry and add dissolve if to the same time fade has on weight paint (if needed) then you have to use the attribute node with dp_wetmap and use the output as fac for anything you want. with that you could recreate the colors weight paint has in obj mode.

works like a charm
ill edit some pics in later

Comment: Please do! I'm trying what I think you're saying to do, but still seeing nothing in the 3D view resembling paint happening.I'm just about to install the proper release rather than RC3 of 2.8, so I'll post if I get any results with that...

Comment: @MarkS sorry, i haven't used blender in more than a year, and i can't remember asking this question...